# Solution to a 1D Fokker-Planck equation with 2 absorbing boundaries and 1 continuity boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Consider the following simple Fokker-Planck equation:
$$\partial_t f(x,t) = a \partial_x^2 f(x,t) $$
which holds on the intervals $x\in(0,c)$ and $(c,b)$. with $0<c<b$.  $0$ and $b$ are absorbing boundaries, while $c$ is a continuity boundary.  $f(x,t)$ is a pdf for $x$, so the boundary conditions for $t>0$ are:
$$f(0,t)=0$$
$$f(b,t)=0$$
$$\int_0^b f(x,t) dx=1$$
and $f(x,t)$ must be continuous at $x=c$.  Finally, there is an initial condition $h(x)$, so the last boundary condition is $f(x,0)=h(x)$.

This is modeling a system where probability exits at the $[0,b]$ boundaries and reenters at $c$.  I would like to know if there is a *general solution* to this problem (or failing that, suggestions to find solutions for simple $h(x)$ initial conditions.)  This is often impossible with PDEs, but two facts give me hope: the stationary distribution is easily solved by pen and paper, and without the integrating condition this reduces to a heat equation which *does* have a general solution.

Thanks!

Comment: By "continuity boundary", do you mean that $f$ is continuous, but $\partial_xf$ may be discontinuous there?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.